# ODBC-ODBC bridge

Tags: mysql, odbc

I have a mysql db running on one linux server.
With an odbc connection for a web server on another linux box.

I would like to be able to use the/an odbc connection to the web server, to access mysql. This would be for an external app that is running on client machines.

I have done some googling, and there might be something called an ODBC-ODBC bridge.

I would like to just get a correct direction to go. So I don't head in the wrong direction.

If someone could point me at a specific bridge software. Or a tutorial. Or if this is even possible, and bridge is the correct thing to look for.  etc...

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your post seems rather confused as to what ODBC is/does.

You have a webserver, you have a database. ODBC wil not join them together. You need something to implement your code with on the webserver - PHP, Perl, Ruby, Python, Java, C....

Bindings are available for most languages to talk to the ODBC client - which typically talks using the databases native protocol to the DBMS. However:

1) ODBC is somewhat constrained in its functionality - since it has to offer the lowest common denominator of functionality across a range of backends

2) all the languages I've listed (and more besides) support native (i.e. full function) connections to MySQL, and to other DBMS

Which rather begs the question, why do you want to to use ODBC?

There are instances where an ODBC-ODBC bridge solves a specific problem - where a DBMS provides an ODBC interface which is not supported on your client. This does not appear to be your problem.

Is your objective here to get the data from the database presented via the webserver or is to build something (anything) using ODBC?

If it's the former then forget about ODBC - it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

your webserver should have odbc connection to connect to MySQL database, and yes that you have. and when you do have that connectivity, I guess you won't really need your clients to connect to the MySQL database directly. because whatever query you want to run (an insert, or query operation), you just submit it to the webserver and it'll give fetch the query results for you.